# How get subtotals of rows and final value of debt

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using Delphi 10.4 and Firebird 3. I have a database with separate tables of incomes, sales, income's payments, sale's payments.

Partners table has 3 fields for storing starting debt of partner at the moment application was installed :

- `idt` (initial financial debt) if the owe me (for example, 10000)
- `myidt` if I owe them (for example, -10000).
- `idt_date` starting date of debt, for example debt on 01/01/2020.

Lets suppose I have to calculate final debt on specific date, for example, on 20/05/2023.

I must:

- take starting debt value (`idt`/`myidt`)
- minus summas of incomes in interval (01/01/2020 - 20/05/2023)
- plus summas of sales in interval
- minus summas of his payments
- plus summas of my payments

and I get final debt on 20/05/2023.

My final aim is get data like this:

starting debt (01/01/2020): 10 000

| Partner_id | DocId | DocDate | incomes | sales | payments | MyPayments | final debt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 05.05.2020 | 500 |  |  |  | 9500 |
| 11 | 144 | 08.08.2020 |  | 200 |  |  | 970 |
| 11 | 205 | 10.04.2021 |  | 400 |  |  | 10100 |
| 11 | 351 | 15.05.2022 | 2000 |  |  |  | 8100 |
| 11 | 1025 | 20.05.2023 |  |  | 500 |  | 7600 |

How may I get such subtotals (debt at specific time) and final debt on 20/05/2023?

It's query what I can write and result table however I know it's not what I expected:

| Partner_id | DocId | DocDate | incomes | sales | payments | MyPayments | final debt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 05.05.2020 | 500 |  |  |  | -500 |
| 11 | 144 | 08.08.2020 |  | 200 |  |  | 200 |
| 11 | 205 | 10.04.2021 |  | 400 |  |  | 400 |
| 11 | 351 | 15.05.2022 | 2000 |  |  |  | -2000 |
| 11 | 1025 | 20.05.2023 |  |  | 500 |  | -500 |

```
 select
     Partner_id,
     Docid,
     DocDate,
     Incomes,
     Sales,
     Payments,
     MyPayments,
     -coalesce(Incomes,0)+coalesce(Sales,0)-coalesce(Payments,0)+ coalesce(MyPayments,0) as 
                                                                                         debt
   from
     (
     Select                                       --incomes
      Partner.partner_id,
      Incomes.Docid,
      Incomes.DocDate,
      Incomes.summa as Incomes,
      0 as Sales,
      0 as Payments,
      0 as MyPayments
      from Incomes, partners
      where 
        Incomes.partner_id= partners.partner_id and 
        Partners.partner_id= :partner_id and
        Incomes.DocDate>=partners.ifd_date and Incomes.DocDate<=:d 
        
        
      union all
    
     Select                                      --Sales 
      Partners.partner_id,
      Sales.Docid,
      Sales.DocDate,
      0,
      Sales.summa,
      0,
      0
      from Sales, Partners
      where 
        Sales.partner_id=partners.partner_id and 
        Partners.partner_id= :partner_id and
        Sales.Docdate>=partners.ifd_date and Sales.DocDate<=:d 
        
        
      union all
     
      
     Select                                      --Payments 
      Partners.partner_id,        
      Payments.Docid,
      Payments.DocDate,
      0,
      0,
      Payments.summa,
      0
     from Payments, partners
     where 
       Payments.partner_id=partners.partner_id and 
       Partners.partner_id= :partner_id and
       Payments.DocDate>=partners.ifd_dt and Payments.DocDate<=:d 
       

     union all
     
      
     Select                                      --MyPayments 
      Partners.partner_id,        
      MyPayments.Docid,
      MyPayments.DocDate,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      MyPayments.summa
     from MyPayments, partners
     where 
       MyPayments.partner_id=partners.partner_id and
       Partners.partner_id= :partner_id and
       MyPayments.DocDate>=partners.ifd_dt and 
       MyPayments.DocDate<=:d 
       
      
  ) DerivedTable1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with DDL for tables and DML for generating example data that fits your expected results.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I created fiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/u2HTQJOp. Can you please correct it as parameter name gets sql error: 'Column unknown PARTNER_ID '

Comment: dbfiddle doesn't support parameters. You need to put in actual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example, with your test data

```sql
select
      p.Partner_id,partner
     ,ifd,myifd,ifd_date
     ,d.Docid,d.DocDate
     ,d.Oper
     ,case when oper='Income' then -d.summa end Incomes
     ,case when oper='Sale' then d.summa end Sales
     ,case when oper='Payment' then -d.summa end Payments
     ,case when oper='MyPayment' then d.summa end MyPayments
     ,d.summa
     ,(p.ifd+p.myifd)+sum(d.summa)
           over(partition by d.partner_id order by d.docdate,d.docid) as tot
   from Partners p left join
     (                         --incomes
     Select 'Income' as oper,partner_id,Docid,DocDate,-summa as summa  from Incomes
     union all
     Select 'Sale' as oper,partner_id,Docid,DocDate,summa  from Sales
     union all
     Select 'MyPayment' as oper,partner_id,Docid,DocDate,summa  from MyPayments
     union all
     Select 'Payment' as oper,partner_id,Docid,DocDate,-summa as summa from Payments
     ) d on d.partner_id=p.partner_id
    where d.docdate>=p.ifd_date and d.docdate<=DATE'2023-05-20'
```

Query result as draft

| P.ID | Name | IFD | MYIFD | IFD_DATE | DOCID | DOCDATE | OPER | INCOMES | SALES | PAYMENTS | MYPAYMENTS | SUMMA | TOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Firm1 | 10000.00 | 0.00 | 2020-01-01 | 21 | 2020-05-05 | Income | 500.00 | null | null | null | -500.00 | 9500.00 |
| 11 | Firm1 | 10000.00 | 0.00 | 2020-01-01 | 144 | 2020-08-08 | Sale | null | 200.00 | null | null | 200.00 | 9700.00 |
| 11 | Firm1 | 10000.00 | 0.00 | 2020-01-01 | 205 | 2021-04-10 | Sale | null | 400.00 | null | null | 400.00 | 10100.00 |
| 11 | Firm1 | 10000.00 | 0.00 | 2020-01-01 | 351 | 2022-05-15 | Income | 2000.00 | null | null | null | -2000.00 | 8100.00 |
| 11 | Firm1 | 10000.00 | 0.00 | 2020-01-01 | 1025 | 2022-05-15 | Payment | null | null | 2000.00 | null | -2000.00 | 6100.00 |

> why does you use over(partition by d.partner_id order by...) analytical function

To calculate accumulated amount from first doc to current. `initial financial debt + accumulated amount = current financial debt`

Windows aggregate function `sum(d.summa)over()` - calculate sum for column d.summa  for  current row and all rows before current row in `order by docdate and docid` - accumulated amount.
For example, with doc (205,2021-04-10)  sum -500+200+400=100. with ifd=10000 current balance=10000+100=10100.
Another doc (1025,2022-05-15) - sum calculated as -500+200+400-2000-2000=-3900. with ifd=10000-3900=6100 final debt.
Additional ordering by DocId is necessary for order doc 351 and 1025, when they have same date.
Partitioning by partner_id is necessary to calculate sum for each partner separately.

You can calculate totals for type operation "Sales"

`sum(d.sales)over(partition by d.partner_id) as total_sales`
this calculates total Sales for partner(partner_id). We do not use in this case order clause in over() - calculate total Sales (200+400=600) for partner.

`count(*)over(partition by d.partner_id) as total_operations` (=5) this calculate rows count for partner_id.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EJmBONTZ)

Comment: @VaINik it works fine.  But I have one question: why does you use over(partition by d.partner_id order by...)  analytical function?  How do I know it is necessary to use it?  What does it make in my case?  May you explain, please.